# Getting a twitter api object out of the twit function

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, twitter

I'm searching for twitter trends using the node [twit library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twit) but I can't figure out how to get the data out of the twit function.

I have this

```
var Twit = require('twit');
var trends = {};

var T = new Twit({/*env data in here*/});

T.get('trends/place', { id: '23424977' }, function(err, reply) {

  trends.obj = reply;
  console.log("1", trends);

}); 

console.log("2", trends);
```

the console returns

```
2 {}
1 { obj: 
   [ { trends: [Object],
       as_of: '2017-10-07T18:13:02Z',
       created_at: '2017-10-07T18:08:50Z',
       locations: [Object] } ] }
```

With a normal function I could just add the twit object to the trends object. But here it's a no go. The console output seems to indicate that it has something to do with the order things are being executed in but I'm not sure how to deal with that. Thanks!

Comment: I think you understand properly... you just need to put the code that uses `reply` inside the function that actually receives it. This is how asynchronous code works in JavaScript (via callbacks), so you'll need to just learn how to do that.

Comment: You're right. The second console log gets executed before you get data from Twitter. Why not just print it inside the call back? Or you can make a function that gets the trend and returns a promise.